# Kivy - hard to select Widgets

Tags: android, python, kivy

I have written a simple application and deployed it on Sony Xperia Z and Galaxy Prime devices. On both it's really very hard (I've got to click many times before it reacts) to:

- put focus on a TextInput
- select a ToggleButton
- click a Button
- etc.

The same time a ScrollView (that is the container for the mentioned widgets) works perfectly smooth. And when run on desktop then it's alright.

I use kivy 1.9.1, python 2.7, build on Ubuntu 16 using buildozer. Don't know what else could I say... (Let me know, please)
Have you experienced such an issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should update to kivy 1.9.2-dev, the problem is fixed there. In `buildozer.spec` file, write requirement `kivy==master`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But in turn scroll view sucks here:/ I have a scroll view with many toggle buttons and it's imposible to scroll without selecting/deselecting some of them. Do you have any hint regarding that?

Comment: It was a problem with nested ScrollView that is a subject of issue: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/2986